# radiobutton event not firing AFTER any other object events

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an asp:radionbutton that will display a popup when clicked to the user asking them a yes/no question.

My jquery works perfect unless I click on another button or any other event first.

I've tried all different ways of writing the radio change or click function based on the searching I've done on the web with no luck.  So I'm posting my code to see if someone knows what I'm missing:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnl_CNs" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
  <ContentTemplate> 
      <asp:Button id="btnGetCNs" Text="Get CNs"  Font-Size="Smaller" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:FetchCNs()"/> / <asp:RadioButton ID="rbCN" CssClass="cssRB" runat="server" Text="Enter CN(s)"  Checked="false"/>   
  </ContentTemplate>
</UpdatePanel>
```

jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input:radio').click(function () {
        alert("hi");
        if (this.data == true) { }
        confirm("Add CN to current List?", function () {
            //alert(this.data);

            var result = this.data;
            if (result == false) {
                $('.csslbCNs').empty();
            }
            //change CN count
            $('.csstbCN').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('.csstbCN:first').focus();
        });
    })

})

function FetchCNs() {
    var rb = $('.cssrbCN');
    rb.attr("checked", false);
    var ln = document.getElementById('<% =ddlLineNumber.ClientID %>').value;
    var cs = document.getElementById('<% =ddlCS.ClientID %>').value;
    PageMethods.FetchCNs(ln, cs, CallSuccess, CallFailed);
}

function CallSuccess(data) {

    var dataLen = data.length;

    var listbox = $('.csslbCNs');
    //listbox.empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        var cn = data[i]["CNNumber"];

        listbox.append('<option>' + cn + '</option>');  
    }
    var CNCountString = "Total CNs: " + i.toString();

    $('.cssCNCount').text(CNCountString);
}
function CallFailed(result) { alert(result.get_message()); }

</script>
```

Comment: Not sure to understand your issue but you should use `change` event for radio button, not click

Comment: Instead of `.click(function() {` try `$('body').on('click','input:radio', function() {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you set your javascript only to be called when the page is ready. When you do an update using update panel your page isn't loaded again, but separate sections are updated. These sections contain new html that needs your javascript function to initialize the controls again.

You can trigger the initialize controls for both initial load as for updated update panels using the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    if (Sys != undefined) {
        //There's a ScriptManager on the page
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_endRequest(PartialPostBackFinished);

        if (!prm.get_isInAsyncPostBack()) {
            //Trigger initialization for synchronous post back triggered outside updatepanels
            InitializeControls(document);
        }
    }
    else {
        //Trigger initialization for pages without ScriptManager
        InitializeControls(document);
    }
}

function PartialPostBackFinished(sender, args) {
    var updatePanels = args.get_panelsUpdated();
    for (i = 0; i < updatedPanels.length; i++) {
        //Do whatever needs to be triggered for each updated update panel
        InitializeControls(updatedPanels[i]);
    }
}

function InitializeControls(container) {
    //Initialise whatever you want to
    $('input:radio', container).click(function () {
        alert("hi");
        if (this.data == true) { }
        confirm("Add CN to current List?", function () {
            //alert(this.data);

            var result = this.data;
            if (result == false) {
                $('.csslbCNs').empty();
            }
            //change CN count
            $('.csstbCN').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('.csstbCN:first').focus();
        });
    })
}

</script>
```

Pay attention to the container added to your jQuery selector, which results in only subscribing to the click event for controls in the container, which should be the updated sections only. This avoids subscribing another time for controls that have not been updated. In your case it might not make a difference, but I think it's good to add that logic to the pattern for future reference.